# playframework: model management

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework.

Is there a model generate and model migration tool like rails

```
rails generage
rake db:migrate
```

and is there a place like rails

app/models dedicated directory for models?
What directory id recommended for models?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model generation**

By default, Play tracks your database evolutions using several ***evolutions script***. These scripts are written in plain `old SQL` and should be located in the `conf/evolutions/{database name}` directory of your application.

**How to migrate?**

Each script contains two parts:

```
The Ups part the describe the required transformations.
The Downs part that describe how to revert them.
```

Here's a link: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Evolutions

**To answer your question: Which directory is recommended/convention for play models definition?**

```
Here's the recommended play project layout:

app                      → Application sources
 └ assets                → Compiled asset sources
    └ stylesheets        → Typically LESS CSS sources
    └ javascripts        → Typically CoffeeScript sources
 └ controllers           → Application controllers
 └ models                → Application business layer
 └ views                 → Templates
conf                     → Configurations files and other non-compiled resources (on classpath)
 └ application.conf      → Main configuration file
 └ routes                → Routes definition
public                   → Public assets
 └ stylesheets           → CSS files
 └ javascripts           → Javascript files
 └ images                → Image files
project                  → sbt configuration files
 └ build.properties      → Marker for sbt project
 └ Build.scala           → Application build script
 └ plugins.sbt           → sbt plugins
lib                      → Unmanaged libraries dependencies
logs                     → Standard logs folder
 └ application.log       → Default log file
target                   → Generated stuff
 └ scala-2.10.0            
    └ cache              
    └ classes            → Compiled class files
    └ classes_managed    → Managed class files (templates, ...)
    └ resource_managed   → Managed resources (less, ...)
    └ src_managed        → Generated sources (templates, ...)
test                     → source folder for unit or functional tests
```

As you can see, user-defined model goes under `app/models`.  It is really up to you regarding the specific model layout under this directory.

Comment: THanks, What directory is recommanded/convention  for play models definitaion `http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/model` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at the Migrate plugin too, it's modelled after the Rails' `db:migrate`:

http://www.playframework.com/modules/migrate-1.4/home